# how to connect to a local host using winsock2

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock2

I wrote this program to communicate internally with a server listening on port 27015. But the return value from the `connect()` give me error 10047. There was no problem with socket creating and `getaddrinfo()` return wasn't an error. I don't know why the socket won't connect, could it be a problem with the concert of network-byte and host-byte?

```c
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
using namespace std;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    // Initialize Winsock version 2.2
    int ret;
    // holds server info//
    if (ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0){
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed with error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        cout << "The current status is:" << wsaData.szSystemStatus << "\n";
    }
      
    // Setup Winsock communication code here
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
       
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    int iResult = getaddrinfo("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    SOCKET Sending_socket; 
      
    Sending_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (Sending_socket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        cout << "socket error\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
     
    // now we connect to the server ,RetCode=return of connect()
    int RetCode = connect(Sending_socket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (RetCode != 0) {
        int num_attempt = 0;
        while (RetCode != 0 && num_attempt != 100){
            printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            RetCode = connect(Sending_socket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
            num_attempt++;
        }        
    }
    else {
        cout << "connect okay \n";
    }
    int them ;
    closesocket(Sending_socket);
    // When your application is finished call WSACleanup
    them = WSACleanup();
    // making sure to cleanup
    if (them != 0){
        cout << "WSACleanup failed with error " << WSAGetLastError();
        // and exit
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `inet_addr` doesn't resolve anything. It converts IP addresses from string to binary. `localhost` is not an IP address.

Comment: To resolve a hostname to an IP address, use `getaddrinfo()`

Comment: i use the getaddrinfo() to get the localhost: ` getaddrinfo("localhost",DEFAULT_PORT , &hints, &result)` then connect: `connect(Sending_socket,result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);` but still error prevail @Remy

Comment: @AsareAgyeiHarrison then you are not using `getaddrinfo()` correctly. 10049 is `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL`: "*This can also result from connect ... **when the remote address or port is not valid for a remote computer** (for example, address or port 0).*" Are you checking the return value of `getaddrinfo()` for failure before calling `connect()`? How are you populating `hints` when calling `getaddrinfo()`? Please [edit] your question to show the new code you have tried.

Comment: the error is now 10047 @Remy

Comment: @AsareAgyeiHarrison That is because you are still misusing `getaddrinfo()`. I have posted an answer explaining why.

Comment: Have you considered looking up Winsock error 10047?

Comment: thanks guys everything is working fine now

Comment: Hi,if any answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Error 10047 is `WSAEAFNOSUPPORT`, which happens when you try to give `connect()` an IP address whose family is not supported by the socket that is being connected, ie by passing an `AF_INET` address to an `AF_INET6` socket, or an `AF_INET6` address to an `AF_INET` socket.  In this case, the latter is happening.

And the reason this is happening is because your call to `memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));` is in the wrong place!

You declare the `hints` variable and *don't* zero it out initially, then you start to fill it in for an `AF_INET` socket, but then you zero it out with `memset()` just before you give it to `getaddrinfo()`.  So `getaddrinfo()` sees the `hints.ai_family` value is 0 (`AF_UNSPEC`) thus giving permission for `getaddrinfo()` to return EITHER/BOTH an IPv4 OR/AND an IPv6 address for `"localhost"`.  Most likely, `getaddrinfo()` is outputting an `AF_INET6` address at the front of the output list (remember, `getaddrinfo()` outputs a null-terminated *linked list* of resolved IP addresses).

Then you proceed to create a new socket using a hard-coded `AF_INET` as the socket family, instead of using the value from `result->ai_family`, and then you give `result->ai_addr` to `connect()`, which fails with error 10047 if that IP address is an `AF_INET6` address and not an `AF_INET` address.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int ret;

    // Initialize Winsock version 2.2
    ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed with error " << ret << "\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "The current status is:" << wsaData.szSystemStatus << "\n";
      
    // Setup Winsock communication code here
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints)); // <-- MOVED HERE!!!
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
       
    ret = getaddrinfo("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "getaddrinfo failed: " << ret << "\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKET Sending_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    for (int num_attempt = 0; num_attempt < 100; ++num_attempt)
    {
        Sending_socket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
        if (Sending_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std::cout << "socket failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            return 0;
        }

        // now we connect to the server
        ret = connect(Sending_socket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
        if (ret == 0)
            break;

        std::cout << "Error at socket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

        closesocket(Sending_socket);
        Sending_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    /* alternatively:

    SOCKET Sending_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    for (int num_attempt = 0; Sending_socket == INVALID_SOCKET && num_attempt < 100; ++num_attempt)
    {
        for(ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
        {
            Sending_socket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
            if (Sending_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                std::cout << "socket failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
                freeaddrinfo(result);
                WSACleanup();
                return 0;
            }
     
            // now we connect to the server
            ret = connect(Sending_socket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
            if (ret == 0)
                break;

            std::cout << "Error at socket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

            closesocket(Sending_socket);
            Sending_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
    }
    */

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (Sending_socket != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "connect okay\n";

        // use Sending_socket as needed...

        closesocket(Sending_socket);
        ret = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "connect not okay\n";
        ret = 0;
    }

    // When your application is finished call WSACleanup
    WSACleanup();

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Use `getaddrinfo` instead.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo)

Quoting Microsoft's documentation for [inet_addr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-inet_addr)

> The `inet_addr` function converts a string containing **an IPv4 dotted-decimal address** into a proper address for the `IN_ADDR` structure.

Emphasis mine. No dotted decimal address, no address.

Also worth noting from the documentation page's section on the return value,

> If the string in the `cp` parameter does not contain a legitimate Internet address, for example if a portion of an "a.b.c.d" address exceeds 255, then `inet_addr` returns the value `INADDR_NONE`.

Always check the return value to make sure it's not giving an error message.

Comment: Sorry I didn't actually bother providing a solution the first time around